# Appium Tests Screenshot folder delete programmatically

Tags: ruby, cucumber, appium

I am taking screen shots on each scenarios for report purpose. But folder size is increasing each time. Is there any way to delete old screen shots automatically?

Comment: Define a nightly cron job that will delete all files older than 1 day in that folder?

Comment: Thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write below code in hooks.rb file. It will delete all the screenshots before creating new screen shots for each new report.

```
AfterConfiguration do
  FileUtils.rm_r("screenshots_folder_name") if File.directory?("screenshots_folder_name")
end
```